# MYSQL; IF then SET statement

Tags: mysql

Can't seem to make below statement work, any suggestions?

```
Set @input := '1234567';
if length(@input)= 7 then SET id=@input; end if;
```

Thanks in advance,

Rene

Comment: What's the data type of `id`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set @input := '1234567';
SELECT IF(length(@input)=7, @input, '((something here))') AS id;
```